# Emacs 25.3.2: reverse windows on files opening

Tags: window, command-line-arguments

If I open 2 files by command line:

```
emacs file1 file2
```

in `Emacs 25.3.2`, `file2` is opened in the **upper** window and `file1` in the **lower**.

[image]

This didn't happen in previous versions of `Emacs` that had the correct (in my opinion) behaviour (`file1` was open in the upper window and `file2` in the lower).

Can I restore the old behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to you init.el file.

```
;; 15-Oct-20  wr  open first file in left window
(defun my-startup-layout ()
  (let ((buffers (mapcar 'window-buffer (window-list))))
    (when (= 2 (length buffers))
      (delete-other-windows)
      (set-window-buffer (split-window-horizontally) (cadr buffers))))
)

(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'my-startup-layout)
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'next-multiframe-window)
;; end of customization to open first file on left
```